# Android Studio missing "General Settings for Project"

Tags: android, android-studio

When I "Open Module Settings" in Android Studio I no longer see "General Settings for Project" (Project Name, Project SDK, Project Language Level, ...).

Is this a bug, a usability problem or am I doing something "wrong" here?

The module-specific settings and SDK location are all that is accessible.

[image]

Comment: Is this a Gradle-based project? What version of Android Studio were you running before?

Comment: It is using Gradle.  I was using 0.5.4, but just upgraded to 0.5.5 to see if that would fix the issue.  I created a new project and the settings appeared, then they disappeared as well.  I then created a third project and the project settings sere missing from the start.  I'm guessing bug?

Answer (score 2):

This is working as intended. These are the only settings you should need for Gradle-based projects. If you were seeing those other settings (which come from the IntelliJ side of things and don't make sense for Gradle projects), it was a bug.

Comment: then how can we use this in android studio

Comment: @ Scott Barta then how can we use this in android studio gradle

Comment: then how can we use this in android studio gradle